# Conditional ASP.NET Repeater

Tags: asp.net, .net

It's my Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterWeb" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="productWrapper">
    <div class="productWrapperImage"><img src="prdimg/<%# Trim(Eval("ProductImage")).ToString()%>" /></div>
    <div class="fontTrebuchet"><%# Trim(Eval("ProductShortInfo")).ToString()%></div>
    <h3 class="fontUbuntu productBoxName"><%# Trim(Eval("ProductName")).ToString()%></h3>
    </div>
    <!--This div my problem--><div class="verticalProductsSpacer"></div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I feed the **Repeater** with 4 rows of data from database, first three `<div class="verticalProductsSpacer"></div>` are necessary but the last one shouldn't be existed. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User a SeparatorTemplate:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterWeb" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="productWrapper">
        <div class="productWrapperImage"><img src="prdimg/<%# Trim(Eval("ProductImage")).ToString()%>" /></div>
        <div class="fontTrebuchet"><%# Trim(Eval("ProductShortInfo")).ToString()%></div>
        <h3 class="fontUbuntu productBoxName"><%# Trim(Eval("ProductName")).ToString()%></h3>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <div class="verticalProductsSpacer"></div>
    </SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Can you explain how to deal with it?

Comment: There is the code example that shows you. This will only put your `verticalProductsSpacer` between each repeater item, which I think is what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: hmm, definitely should work - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.separatortemplate(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I'm interested in in something like **IF** statement, if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery to hide it.

```
$('.verticalProductsSpacer').last().css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: This worked in my case, thank. But I'm looking for another solution.

Comment: You should try the method in @Prescott's answer. That is a better solution.